# A layout similar to WhatsApp conversation

Tags: extjs, layout

I want to create a simple IM program using Sencha ExtJS 6 modern toolkit. In the conversation panel, I dynamically add a new panel for each sent/received message. Sent messages should be aligned to the right and received messages should be aligned to the left (just like Whatsapp conversation).

I tried "VBOX" layout, but it applies the alignment (left or right) to all messages. There is a layout called "Ext.layout.float", but I couldn't make it do the job, as it is not well-documented.

How can I get the desired layout?

Thanx

Comment: If you can separate between send messages and received messages, you could use a XTemplate in order to use `float:left` or `float:right` in the panels(divs) which represents the messages.

Comment: I tried `float:right`with "vbox" layout, but it does not work. The panel stays aligned to the left. I used `float:right`with the default layout of the panel, the child panel gets out of the context of the surrounding child panels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of vbox and hbox layout with flex config. Here is an example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/19oo

Comment: How can I limit the width of the message panels to 80% of the container width in your solution?

Comment: Simply add `width: '80%'` to the message panel.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of using a dataview and css to achieve it:

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/19n9)

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function() {
        var store = new Ext.data.Store({
            fields: ['text'],
            data: (function() {
                var data = [],
                    i;

                for (i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
                    data.push({
                        text: 'Message' + (i + 1)
                    });
                }
                return data;
            })()
        });

        Ext.Viewport.add({
            xtype: 'dataview',
            store: store,
            itemTpl: '<div class="clearfix"><div style="float: {[xindex % 2 === 0 ? "left" : "right"]};">{text}</div></div>'
        });
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
.clearfix:after { 
   content: " ";
   display: block; 
   height: 0; 
   clear: both;
}
```